# change names of all files in a directory to random strings

Tags: bash, file, random, rename

Purpose:

- change names of all files in a directory to random strings of the same length
- list this files in another file (with a possibility to make from it sql query )

I think bash would be great for it, but I have no idea how to do this, can you help me?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: @Dave Those files are images. I want to use those in browser-based game and I dont want to user hack the game and know what image is next in this game by making guesses on what is the adress of the image.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I've got no help for you, though; I was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many ways... for example:

```
random_string() { 
  echo "$(date +%s%N)$RANDOM" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}' 
}

find /path/to/files -type f | while read FILE; do 
  EXTENSION=${FILE##*.}
  mv "$FILE" "$(dirname "$FILE")/$(random_string).$EXTENSION"
done
```